# Does anything of this 1988 “TeX in CWEB” still exist?

Tags: tex-core, tex-history, cweb

In TUGboat 9:2 (1988), there is an interesting article titled “[TeX adapted to `CWEB`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-2/tb21kennedy.pdf)”, written by David Kennedy of Micro Publishing Systems, Inc.

[Literate programming historians should note that the `CWEB` being referred to is indeed Silvio Levy's 1987 `CWEB` [(TUGboat 8:1)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb08-1/tb17levy.pdf), not that of Guntermann and Schrod [(TUGboat 7:3)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb07-3/tb16gunterweb.pdf). Today only Levy's `CWEB` is well known.]

Here is the beginning of the article:

> This article announces TeX in `CWEB`, a new
> starting point for TeX ports. We have recently
> completed the translation of TeX to `CWEB`, a
> version of Don Knuth's `WEB` system of structured
> documentation, entirely rewritten in C, with many
> changes to take advantage of features found in C,
> but not in Pascal.

The translation was apparently proprietary, although the source code could be obtained for a fee.

I don't have high hopes, but has this implementation been archived somewhere? Is there any way to access the code today? Complete, fresh (i.e., not derived directly from Knuth's code), literate implementations of TeX are very rare (in fact, I can't think of any). It would probably be possible to compile and run the program, if it is still around.

Comment: I'm guessing probably not. There's a lot of source code of that era which has largely vanished. My VM/CMS DVI previewer DVIVIEW is something that I suspect is also gone forever. LIkewise, change files for VAX/VMS that I updated also seem gone.

Comment: @DonHosek That's what I expect as well. But it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: Not related to this question but related to your second paragraph in brackets: There was also another `cweb`, by [Harold Thimbleby](http://www.harold.thimbleby.net/cv/warp.html). And (still not exactly an answer), you probably know about [web2w](https://ctan.org/pkg/web2w) (a semi-automated CWEB conversion of tex.web), and there were/are "manual" translations of tex.web into C or C++, like (c. late 1980s) Pat Monardo's CommonTeX, [LuaTeX](http://luatex.org/talks/taco-luatex-eurotex2009.pdf), and ["rsTeX"](https://github.com/nadder/rstex).

Comment: At these old times I had a copy of many implementation variants and different approaches (including Pat Monardo's C reimplementation).  But you have to remember that 1988 means TeX 2, not TeX 3, which means that you have to manually apply all TeX 3 changes applied by DEK in 1989 to the old "TeX" CWEB code. (Interesting with respect to TeX history, for sure.)  And then you still miss all additions which are nowadays incorporated in the pdf/e-/...-TeX you are really using.